# HTML Form data into a Object to pass a method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a basic cash register app. How do I pass the form data from this:

```
<form action="#" id="target">
<input type="text" required class="field1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-3" placeholder="Enter Item Name Here">
<input type="text" required class="field1 col-sm-2 " placeholder="Enter Item Quantity">
</div>
<div class="row">
<input type="text" class="field1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-3" placeholder="Enter Staff Name (Optional)">
<button type='submit' class="col-md-2 butn btn-one" id="check">Checkout</button>
</div>
```

into the methods listed below everytime something is submitted

```
cashRegister.scan('ITEM NAME', QUANTITY);
// Apply your staff discount
// applying a staff discount to the total amount

cashRegister.applyStaffDiscount(EMPLOYEE);
```

then print the results of the script from the console to the HTML page

```
console.log('Your bill is ' + cashRegister.total.toFixed(2));
```

I want to be able input a quantity of 5 for an item of apples, on my discount and have that form spit out this following JavaScript to execute this script http://codepen.io/illusionelements/pen/xGQrxN

```
(item: apple, quantity: 5, Employee:me)
cashRegister.scan('apple',5);
cashRegister.applyStaffDiscount(me);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem you're having is that you're trying to get the values of the form to the javascript. If that's the case then try something like this:

```
$('#check').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //Stops the form from being posted
    var item = $('#item').val();
    var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
    var staff = $('#staff').val();

    cashregister.scan(item, quantity);
    if(staff.length > 0 && typeof staffMembers[staff] != 'undefined')
    {
        cashregister.applyStaffDiscount(staffMembers[staff]);
    }

    console.log('Your bill is ' + cashRegister.total.toFixed(2));

    $('#target2').fadeIn(5000)
      // .animate({opacity: 0.5}, 3000)
      .fadeOut(5000);
});
```

A couple things you'd need to do to make this work:

- give your inputs unique classes or ids
- make an object of your staff members

  ```
   var staffMembers = {};
   var sally = new StaffMember("Sally", 5);
   staffMembers['sally'] = sally;
  ```

Comment: So using this method there is no need to pass on the form data into json format?

Comment: No, you're grabbing the values directly from the input fields when the user clicks a button.